# Representing $su(2)$ Lie algebra on a torus

Tags: angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I've recently taken up the study of QFT (as a post retirement hobby),  based on  texts by David Tong  and Anthony Zee.

My question is based on the Lie Algebra of the $SU(2)$ group, and how this may be represented on a manifold such as the 3 (real) dimensional torus.

In particular, I would like to know how I should understand in what way the spin operator commutation operation
 $[S_x, S_y] = S_z$ is to be understood when performed on a torus.

I'm not necessarily looking for a direct answer, as a series of images may be too time consuming to produce. I have read Penrose's "Road to Reality" which I thought might give me the best geometrical picture, but no direct answer exists there.

As a self study person, I apologize if I am  mistaken in my intuition as to what the torus actually represents.

In reply to the comment below:

I mean "representing" in a general manner, rather than something formal  like matrix representation

I  mean is there a duality type setup? Can we use the shape of the torus to find out more about the properties of spin half particles?

Another way of asking the question:  is there  any physical intuition for choosing a torus, and if so how does the shape of the torus reflect spin half particles or is it just a formal mathematical mapping?

My thoughts are that the torus is just another way of looking at the problem, and that there should be equivalent operations on it, but I might be reading too much into it,

Edit to include comments, as this question is based on an incorrect assumption of mine, but someone might find it useful:

> Just to make sure: you want to represent the Lie algebra as a manifold, not the group? Because SU(2) the group is the manifold S3, but probably that's not what you are after. 
>   Also, every Lie group has a subgroup which is a torus and it's generated by the exponential of the Cartan subalgebra. In the case of SU(2), which is of rank 1, the torus is just a circle.

Comment: Is there some source you are reading where you are getting the idea of "representing SU(2) on a torus"? That's not standard language that I'm aware of. If you could quote some source it might help us understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @lukepritchett. I admit my question is vague, but I have tried to clarify it a bit.

Comment: Just to make sure: you want to represent the Lie *algebra* as a manifold, not the group? Because $SU(2)$ the group is the manifold $S^3$, but probably that's not what you are after.

Comment: Also, every Lie group has a subgroup which is a torus and it's generated by the exponential of the Cartan subalgebra. In the case of $SU(2)$, which is of rank $1$, the torus is just a circle. So again, probably that's not what you are after. Sorry if I'm just throwing stuff at random.

Comment: @MannyC thanks, I did not appreciate the distinction, but I know what to look for now, that's a great help.

Comment: I can’t make sense of this question. I think you may have gotten some misimpressions about Lie algebras and their representations. Can you explain what you read that made you ask this question?

Comment: would this https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1479301 be useful?

Comment: @gsmith I initially read how Dirac sponsors could be described in different representations. I then assumed that the torus was connected with the group and spent a while trying to assign physical correspondences  between the properties of spin half particles and the topology of the surface and half convinced myself it was worth a question. As MannyC pointed out to me, the torus deals with the algebra, not the group. A little knowledge......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the *realization*, **not** representation, of the su(2) Lie algebra, in the spherical basis,
$$
[S_0,S_{\pm}]=\pm S_{\pm} \qquad [S_+,S_-]=2S_{\pm} ~~ ,
$$
in terms of the two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ going around the 2-torus in the respective "directions",
$$
S_+= \phi \partial_\theta, \qquad S_-= \theta \partial_\phi, \qquad  S_0= \phi \partial_\phi -   \theta \partial_\theta ~.
$$

You may easily check they satisfy the Lie algebra.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think there is a more definitive answer than that.

Comment: It can be dressed up as a bonfire of mathematese with Jordan maps, Bargmann realizations, etc, but they'd only obscure the brutish underlying formal structure.